# I would like to know how to apply Excel column B (Powershell source) to the same folder name as Excel column A value

Tags: excel, powershell

There are A, B, C, D, E folders in the "image folder".(C:image)
Excel column A value refers to the folder name in "Image Folder".(Destination)

The Excel column B value is the source of the PowerShell and plays a role of changing the name of the file in the A~E folder.
When the Excel column A and the folder name match, the power cell source in Excel column B is applied at once. In other words, it tries to apply the PowerShell source in column B to each file in folders A to F at once. I want to implement it as a powershell source. Can you help? please

[image]

Comment: Why would you need an Excel sheet at all? Looks like you simply want to rename all jpg files in a subfolder to become `<subfoldername>_<countervalue>.jpg`. Am I right?

Comment: The value of column A on the EXCEL sheet means the folder name. This is to apply PowerShell in column B for each folder.

Comment: Powershell sources to be applied for each folder A to E are written in column B.
I want to apply each folder name that matches the value of column A in Excel. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, the code you use in the Excel is the same for every subfolder mentioned. That is why I don't think you need that Excel at all, it would just provide more overhead.

Why not do

1. Change all filenames inside the (1 level) of subfolders inside the rootfolder:

   ```
   $rootFolder = 'C:\Image'
   Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder -Filter '*.jpg' -File -Recurse -Depth 1 | 
       Group-Object -Property @{Expression = {$_.Directory.Name}} |
       ForEach-Object {
           $dir = $_.Name
           $nr = 1
           foreach ($file in $_.Group) {
               $file | Rename-Item -NewName ('{0}_{1}.jpg' -f $dir, $nr++ ) 
           }
       }
   ```
2. Or if you have more folders inside the C:\Image folder and you want to limit to certain subfolders

   ```
   $rootFolder = 'C:\Image'
   $subfolders = 'A','B','C','D','E'  # array of folders to process
   foreach ($dir in $subfolders) {
       $path = Join-Path -Path $rootFolder -ChildPath $dir
       Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter '*.jpg' -File | 
           Group-Object -Property @{Expression = {$_.Directory.Name}} |
           ForEach-Object {
               $dir = $_.Name
               $nr = 1
               foreach ($file in $_.Group) {
                   $file | Rename-Item -NewName ('{0}_{1}.jpg' -f $dir, $nr++ ) 
               }
           }   
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much. I think the answer will be very helpful. I think I have to change method 2 and use it.

By the way, in column A of Excel, there are more folder names besides the folder in the "image folder". Therefore, by referring to the value of column A in Excel, we try to apply PowerShell in column B to only those that match (convert file name in specific subfolder{0}).

If you are not sure what you mean, please comment. I will go into detail again. I'm sorry. It hasn't been a while since I studied at PowerShell. I am trying.

Comment: You must refer to the Excel column A value and apply the PowerShell source in the Excel column B only to the folder that matches the A value.

Comment: thank you. I modified it to suit my needs and used it really well. I am trying to apply powershell code to numerous folders. If it doesn't work, can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: @AAron Sure, that is what this platform is all about!